# Log only specific properties of exception using NLog

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I would like to configure the NLog.config file(.net framework web app) to log some specific properties of exception.

I want only type,stackTrace and message.

I read this [layout render](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer)

```
${exception:format=String:innerFormat=String:maxInnerExceptionLevel=Integer:innerExceptionSeparator=String
       :separator=String:exceptionDataSeparator=string}
```

but I cannot understand how to log only these properties that I want.

Comment: Maybe give an example of what you have tried, and the unexpected output you received. There are several examples on the Wiki-page you have found yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that other reply was removed, since it was completely correct. Let me write it one more time. The examples below can also be found on the Wiki-page that you have found yourself.

Renders Exception-Message:

```
${exception:Format=Message}
```

Renders Exception-Type:

```
${exception:Format=Type}
```

Renders Exception-StackTrace:

```
${exception:Format=StackTrace}
```

They can also be combined:

```
${exception:Format=Message,Type}
```

If you have issues with unexpected output, then you are probably victim of not properly deploying the updated `NLog.config`.